# Align Text in Javascript append data

Tags: javascript, html, dom, appendchild

I will really appreciated any help. I am trying to fix the display of the text in my html. I use javascript and call the variable and display in html. However the display of the text is not what i desired.

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
      var table= $('#data-table').DataTable({  

           "ajax"     :     "employee_data.json",  
           "columns"     :     [  
                {     "data"     :     "name"     },  
                {     "data"     :     "gender"},  
                {     "data"     :     "designation"},
                {     "data"     :     "image"},    
            {"defaultContent":  '<div style="text-align:center"><button style="width:100%; margin-top: 5px;"  class="btn btn-danger" > support </button></div>'}                     
           ]  

      });
       $('#data-table tbody').on( 'click', 'button', function () {

        var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
        alert( "You Click" + " "+data['name'] );
        $new="You Click" + " "+data['name'] ;

        $images=data['image'];

        $names=document.getElementById("name").append = data['name'];
                $gender=document.getElementById("gender").append = data['gender'];
                $('#img-container').append(data['image']+" " + $names+$gender+" </p>"+"<br>" );

    } );



 });
```

Running Result:
[image: Please see]

Desired Output:
[image: Desired Output]

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your style using this unit of measurement to make it responsive to the sizing.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var table= $('#data-table').DataTable( {
        "ajax"        :     "employee_data.json",  
        "columns"     :     [  
            {     "data"     :     "name"     },  
            {     "data"     :     "gender"},  
            {     "data"     :     "designation"},
            {     "data"     :     "image"},    
            {"defaultContent":  '<div style="font-size:15vw;"><button style="width:100%; margin-top: 5px;"  class="btn btn-danger"> support </button></div>'}                     
       ]  
  });
```

Comment: the table is okay sir. but the problem is when i display all the data in div. i did add new line in the append.  but its not the desired output that i want